# Attach/Render RactiveJS component outside of template

Tags: dynamic, routes, components, render, ractivejs

I've got an existing SPA that was developed using nested RactiveJS components. Which is great, and offers a ton of flexibility throughout the entire app. Currently I attempting to add in client side routing support using [page](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js/). My navigation switches out high-level components using simple `{{#visible}}{{/visible}}` template markup on each component. This is a little troublesome in its current state as it always kicks off a re-render whenever the high-level component *becomes* *visible* again.

Is there a way to render a component, for example, called `widget`, without using the

`<widget></widget>`

method? I've already "registered" the component with the parent, but obviously when constructing it by means of

```
new App.components.widget
```

I am able to control how/when it's rendered/inserted/detached, but lose the recognition in the application's component hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`insert`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-insert) exactly for that. You don't even need to "register" it to the component you plan to put it to. You can use the different `find*` methods or [`nodes`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-nodes) to easily retrieve a reference of your planned container element.

```
var instance = new YourDetachedWidget({ ... });
instance.insert('#your-container'); // This could be a node, selector or jQuery object
```

Comment: It's more of an issue that I am losing the ability to reference the parent ractive instance and its inherited data from a deeply nested component.